# android studio 2.3 プロジェクト作成時、エラーについて

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio 2.3でのプロジェクト作成時、下記のエラー発生したので、エラーの意味と対策を教えてくさい。

C:\Users\vaiot\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\build.gradle

Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Answer (score 2):

Androidの標準パッケージに含まれていない[サポートライブラリ](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html?hl=ja)が足りないという意味のエラーです。
サポートライブラリは新機能の下位互換やUI要素追加のために追加されることが多いです。

[appcompat-v7](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html?hl=ja#v7)が下位互換のために`build.gradle`に記述されていますが、ダウンロードされているでしょうか。

開発用端末にダウンロードする場合は、[Support Library のセットアップ](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html?hl=ja)手順で作業を行ってください。

1. Android SDK Manager を起動します。
2. [SDK Manager] ウィンドウで [Packages] リストを番下までスクロールし、「Extras」フォルダを探して、必要に応じてコンテンツが表示されるように展開します。
3. [Android Support Repository] アイテムを選択します。
4. [Install packages...] ボタンをクリックします。

すでにこの手順を踏んでいて、それでもビルド時にエラーが発生するならばアップデートを行ってください。

#### コメントを受けて追記

手元に環境がないので推測を含む回答になり申し訳ありません。
プロジェクト（ルート直下）のbuild.gradleに、下記の`maven { ... }`を追記すると解決するかどうかお試しください。

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" 
        }
    }
}
```

[類似エラーの解決事例](http://mio.yokohama/?p=428)

> サポートライブラリのバージョン26.0.0以降のリポジトリが変更になり、GoogleのMavenリポジトリ (https://maven.google.com) から利用するようです。
> そこで、プロジェクト（ルート直下）のbuild.gradleを編集します。

[本家SOの解決事例](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45564965)

Comment: 早々と回答ありがとうございます。この手順で行いたいと思います

Comment: SDKのsdkplatforms,SDKToolsをダウンロードし、インストールしましだが,同様なエラーが発生しました

Comment: 回答を追記しました。ご確認をお願いします。

Comment: maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" 
の追記でエラーが無くりました。

Comment: 追記でエラー無くなりました、ありがとうございます。